# Formatting Emails from Sheets in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to format emails from a Google Sheet into a string that I can use as email recipients. I've gotten the emails, and I'm using a for loop to try to remove empty values, but it's not catching ("true" never triggers). Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RPw_sNHF3JTlMYBD_Mk1BTOHDLaXya8IaeuU3YkxHUQ/edit?usp=sharing

Here's my code:

```
function affiliateReportReminder() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var lastRow = sheet.getRange("A1:A").getLastRow();
  var emails = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + lastRow).getValues();
  for (i = 0; i > lastRow; i++) {
    if (emails[i]='') {
      console.log(true)
      emails.splice(i,1);
    }
  } 
  console.log(emails);
};
```

Comment: I don't know if it's a main problem but here`if (emails[i]='') {` should be `==`.

Comment: Did you try the suggested solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### comma separated list of email recipients

```
function affiliateReportReminder() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const emails = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat().join(",");
  console.log(emails);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By the way, if you want to remove empty elements from array you can do it with `array.filter(String)` method. In this case it could be:

```
var emails = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + lastRow).getValues().flat().filter(String);
```

`array.flat()` makes 1D array from 2D array: `[[a],[''],[b]]` --> `[a,'',b]`

`array.filter(String)` removes empty elements: `[a,'',c]` --> `[a,b]`